# Heroku error with with amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

For Image uploads on my ruby-on-rails application I use the ruby gem paperclip, which works great locally. When it comes to webhosting on heroku, I want to use amazon s3 to store pictures. But every time I upload an image, I get the message

> We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

On the web somebody said that I'd have to use a 'aws-sdk' older than v2.0, but unfortunately my console says then

> uninitialized constat aws

so that the website does not run on local host anymore but also not on heroku (I get an application error).

So I sticked with 2.3, which is also used on the heroku [heorku website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3).

The AWS information (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_BUCKET, AWS_REGION, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY...) and the write/read permission should be correct

The **production.rb** part looks like this

```
config.paperclip_defaults = { 
  storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('AWS_BUCKET'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    }
  }
```

The **Gemfile**

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.6'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
```

Anybody an idea what I could do to make it work?

Comment: Why have you not first of all checked the log files, as the message explicitly asked you to do?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't really help me that much. But in one of the lines it said "NameError (uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS" could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
It works to run the if you run the following gems parallel.

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
```

Thats it.